# is there any difference between reduce and reduceBack

Tags: .net, f#

I'm learning f# from msdn and looking and trying out the reduce and reduce back, I can't find any difference, the signature is the same

`('T -> 'T -> 'T) -> 'T list -> 'T`

and they both throw same error on empty list, so why is there 2 of them, there should be some difference

Comment: I suspect it determines if the reduction happens on the left or the right side.

Comment: Don't know f#, but it's probably a [left and right fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) difference.

Comment: on msdn it doesn't say anything about left/right, for reduce it says that it first applies the reduction func on the first 2, for reduceBack it doesn't say that but it still work the same

Comment: @phg there is a fold function in f# just for that

Comment: @phg correct, see also fold/foldBack (which are left and right folds).

Comment: Try out both with a non-commutative function, like division, and see if the results are different (and are correct results for different directions).

Comment: The differnce between `fold` and `reduce` seems to be that fold is more general  and can return a different type (i.e., a "real" fold): `('State -> 'T -> 'State) -> 'State -> 'T list -> 'State`, whereas `reduce` just aggregates over a sequence.

Comment: with `fold` you pass a initial value for the accumulator, `reduce` just uses the first one ; before I was thinking that the only difference between fold and foldBack is the order of the accumulator and list parameters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Others already explained the difference - they reduce elements in a different order.

For most of the operations that you can use with `reduce` or `reduceBack`, the difference does not actually matter. In more mathematical terms, if your operation is [*associative*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) (such as numeric operations, max, min or sum functions, list concatenation, etc.) then the two behave the same.

An example where you can nicely see the difference is building a tree, because that exactly shows how the evaluation works:

```
type Tree = 
  | Leaf of int
  | Node of Tree * Tree

[ for n in 0 .. 3 -> Leaf n]
|> List.reduce (fun a b -> Node(a, b))

[ for n in 0 .. 3 -> Leaf n]
|> List.reduceBack (fun a b -> Node(a, b))
```

Here are the two trees that you get as the result (but note that if you flatten them, then you get the same list!)

```
          reduce        reduceBack
-------------------------------------
tree:       /\              /\
           /\ 3            0 /\
          /\ 2              1 /\
         0  1                2  3
-------------------------------------
flat:    0 1 2 3          0 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look at the MSDN documentation, [reduce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370239) and [reduceBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353624).

For `reduce` it specifies that:

> If the input function is f and the elements are i0...iN, then it
>   computes f (... (f i0 i1) i2 ...) iN.

For `reduceBack` it specifies that:

> If the input function is f and the elements are i0...iN, then this
>   function computes f i0 (...(f iN-1 iN)).

Comment: do you know what the `s` stands for in those notations, for instance for foldBack there is `f i0 (...(f iN s))`, what's `s`

Comment: If I understand correctly, `s` is the initial state in the `foldBack` case. If you look at the Example in the [`foldBack` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353846), I think it should be clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Their main difference is order of evaluation. While `reduce` goes from the first element to the last one, `reduceBack` goes in the reverse order. Notice that the order between the current element and the accumulator is also reversed in `reduceBack`.

A demonstrative example could be:

```
let last xs = List.reduce (fun _ x -> x) xs   
let first xs = List.reduceBack (fun x _ -> x) xs
```